# Looking for a Shonen Jump manga, where a character realizes leveling up will take a long time

Tags: story-identification, manga, shonen-jump

I am looking to find this one specific manga I think I read in an old Shonen Jump in 2003 - 2008.

But after looking at all the possible mangas during that time I couldn't find it.

I only remember: someone killing a bunch of monsters and he realizes that leveling up will take very long or something.

Comment: I'd be surprised if this is enough information for anyone to find it. That's really not a lot to go on. Is there anything else you can remember?

Comment: Did you check this list https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_series_run_in_Weekly_Sh%C5%8Dnen_Jump#2000s ?

Comment: Was it in the American magazine Weekly Shonen Jump, or was it in Japanese or another language? Did it specifically refer to "levelling up"? Do you remember what kind of world it was set in, or how they were killing the monsters? Any details about what the characters looked like?

Answer (score 8):

The details in the question remind me of the first chapter of ***Beet the Vandel Buster***, which I read in *[Shonen Jump Compilation Edition, Volume 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlAZO.jpg)*, published for Fall/Winter 2004.

The chapter opens with the title character, a boy named Beet, undergoing the initiation ritual to become a Buster (monster hunter). Halfway though the chapter, though, [he's struggling to defeat his first monster and mocked by one of his Buster idols for it](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zeiKa.jpg).

Unexpectedly, the leader of this Buster group appears and [gives Beet advice to defeat the monster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8aWXr.jpg). This leads to a conversation where [Beet excitedly asks how many levels he just gained](https://i.stack.imgur.com/avFbW.jpg), **only to be told the monster is worth the least amount of points.**

> **Laio:** "You'll be lucky to reach level 3 even after you kill off a hundred of them."
>
> **Beet:** "... ...A longer road than I expected, huh?"

After a debate with the other two about whether Busters are noble warriors of justice or assassins looking for a paycheck, [Beet turns his attention to fight the rest of the monsters in the pond with the lessons he's been taught](https://i.stack.imgur.com/neYjL.jpg).

The chapter ends with Beet returning to town just in time to see the Buster group battling the toughest and most infamous Vandel (high-ranking monster).

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  This is a really good answer!